# Drawing over text in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, drawing, microsoft-metro

I am creating a drawing metro application for Window 8 using c#. I am Using textblock inside the canvas and Ink-manager for drawing.This work fine but i want to draw a ink only upon the drowntext of textblock not in hole canvas.

Here is code:-

```
<Canvas Name="canvas"  Background="Transparent" >
<TextBlock  x:Name="txtblock" Margin="80,0,0,0" Foreground="White"  
VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="60"/> </Canvas>
```

Please help me how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the most straightforward way is to wrap your `TextBlock` within another `Canvas`.

As such, you will have two `Canvas`, with the child Canvas being positioned within the main Canvas.

One area of concern with this approach would be the sizing of the child `Canvas`, in which needs to be dynamically resized based on the size of the containing `TextBlock`.

```
<Canvas Name="canvas"  Background="Transparent" >
  <Canvas Name="childCanvas" Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock  x:Name="txtblock" Margin="80,0,0,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="60"/> 
  </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... But this is not usefull in my case. I want to draw ink over the drowntext of textblock.